# Multilevel column header for DataGrid in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which needs to look like this:

[image]

As you can see, there are multiple columns as well as multi-level column headers, some that span multiple columns.

I need to do this in WPF, so kindly provide only XAML solutions which will create multi level column headers.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As far as I know, the standard `DataGrid` does not support it, so you need to look for alternatives. I can offer the use of a `Grid` capabilities, such as: [`Grid.RowDefinitions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.rowdefinitions.aspx), [`Grid.ColumnDefinitions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.grid.columndefinitions%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). To illustrate this feature, I created a sample, who need to complete:

```
<Window x:Class="MultiHeaderDataGrid.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Bisque" />
        <Setter Property="TextBlock.FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Row="0">                 
        <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
            <TextBlock Text="Main application" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Column="0">                
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Experiment 1" TextAlignment="Center" />             
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Experiment 2" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Mode 1" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Mode 2" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="2">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Mode 1" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="4">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Mode 2" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.Column="0">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Mode 1" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="1">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Mode 2" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="2">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Mode 1" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>

        <Border Grid.Column="4">
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Mode 2" TextAlignment="Center" />
        </Border>
    </Grid>

    <DataGrid Name="datagrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Row="3" RowHeaderWidth="10" Loaded="datagrid1_Loaded">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column1" Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="column 1" Width="100" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column2" Binding="{Binding Age}"  Header="column 2" Width="80" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column3" Binding="{Binding Sample}" Header="column 3" Width="80" />
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column4" Binding="{Binding Sample}" Header="column 4" Width="*" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

`Output`

[image]

If you want, you can set the `ColumnDefinition Width` of a `Grid`, like a `DataGrid` column:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=SampleDataGrid, Path=RowHeaderWidth}" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column1, Path=ActualWidth}" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column2, Path=ActualWidth}" />
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

Also, you need to define the same `Style` for the `Grid` header and `DataGrid`.

Comment: I have successfully using this.. But I got a problem when the scrolling bar is visible.. The column would reduce itself and the size is not fit with the header again..How I can fix this?

Comment: @mrhands: I can not answer immediately and in comment. You need to ask a new question with an example of what you did it and how it should look like this.

Comment: I have asked question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140746/how-to-fix-width-of-column-in-datagrid-when-horizontal-scrollbar-is-visible

Comment: @mrhands: Okay I see it, if there is a solution, I'll write it.

Answer (score 3):

[image: This is the output of the xaml]

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="400">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <StackPanel Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold">EXPERIMENT 1</Label>
                    <Line Stroke="Black"
                          X1="0"
                          X2="400"
                          Y1="0"
                          Y2="0" />
                    <StackPanel Width="400" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Width="200" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">MODE 1</Label>
                        <Line Stroke="Black"
                              X1="1"
                              X2="1"
                              Y1="0"
                              Y2="26" />
                        <Label Width="200" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">MODE 2</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Line Stroke="Black"
                          X1="0"
                          X2="400"
                          Y1="0"
                          Y2="0" />
                    <StackPanel Width="400" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">VALUE 1</Label>
                        <Line Stroke="Black"
                              X1="1"
                              X2="1"
                              Y1="0"
                              Y2="26" />
                        <Label Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">VALUE 2</Label>
                        <Line Stroke="Black"
                              X1="1"
                              X2="1"
                              Y1="0"
                              Y2="26" />
                        <Label Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">VALUE 1</Label>
                        <Line Stroke="Black"
                              X1="1"
                              X2="1"
                              Y1="0"
                              Y2="26" />
                        <Label Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">VALUE 2</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Width="400" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ComboBox Width="100" />
                        <ComboBox Width="100" />
                        <ComboBox Width="100" />
                        <ComboBox Width="100" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="400">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <StackPanel Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontWeight="Bold">EXPERIMENT 2</Label>
                    <Line Stroke="Black"
                          X1="0"
                          X2="400"
                          Y1="0"
                          Y2="0" />
                    <StackPanel Width="400" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Width="200" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">MODE 1</Label>
                        <Line Stroke="Black"
                              X1="1"
                              X2="1"
                              Y1="0"
                              Y2="26" />
                        <Label Width="200" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">MODE 2</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Line Stroke="Black"
                          X1="0"
                          X2="400"
                          Y1="0"
                          Y2="0" />
                    <StackPanel Width="400" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Label Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">VALUE 1</Label>
                        <Line Stroke="Black"
                              X1="1"
                              X2="1"
                              Y1="0"
                              Y2="26" />
                        <Label Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">VALUE 2</Label>
                        <Line Stroke="Black"
                              X1="1"
                              X2="1"
                              Y1="0"
                              Y2="26" />
                        <Label Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">VALUE 1</Label>
                        <Line Stroke="Black"
                              X1="1"
                              X2="1"
                              Y1="0"
                              Y2="26" />
                        <Label Width="100" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">VALUE 2</Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Width="400" Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ComboBox Width="100" />
                        <ComboBox Width="100" />
                        <ComboBox Width="100" />
                        <ComboBox Width="100" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Override the DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter template.

This will create header rows that have the normal behaviour, which is that they scroll with the datagrid horizontally, but stay fixed when scrolling vertically.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter}">
                        <Grid Background="Red">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Text="MAIN APPLICATION"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Experiment 1"></TextBlock>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Experiment 2"></TextBlock>
                            <DataGridColumnHeader x:Name="PART_FillerColumnHeader" 
                                                  Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                                IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                            <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```