# How to make custom header with data grid in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to make data grid with custom header. My header contains of Row Span and Column Span. So I have decided using `grid` as the layout and then `datagrid` as my control data.

You can see my header like this..
[image: datagrid]

and then below that header I wanna make `datagrid` how I can do it? I'm still newbie in WPF and then how I can make the column in my grid layout can match `datagrid` that I have created below that?

Comment: Please see my [`answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652039/multilevel-column-header-in-datagridview-wpf/17653328#17653328), namely the last paragraph.

Comment: @mrhands - Please close your question if you have found a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multilevel column header for DataGrid in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652039/multilevel-column-header-for-datagrid-in-wpf)