# How to fix width of Column in DataGrid when Horizontal Scrollbar is Visible?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I using the complex header with datagrid like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652039/multilevel-column-header-for-datagrid-in-wpf/17653328). But I got problem of the scrollbar visibility it also spend a space so the width can not perfectly match with the grid. My Grid is just like this in `<Column.Definition>`

```
  <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column1, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column2, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column3, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column4, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column5, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column6, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
  <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=Column7, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
... till column 29
```

Anda I have data grid for `Column.Definition` like this

```
 <DataGrid.Columns>
<mui:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column1"  Width="50" Header="Segmen"  Binding="{Binding B4R1,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<mui:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column2" Width="50" Header="Fisik" Binding="{Binding B4R2,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged , Mode=TwoWay}" />
<mui:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column3" Width="50" Header="Sensus" Binding="{Binding B4R3,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged , Mode=TwoWay}"/>
<mui:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column4" Width="50" Header="Tempat Tinggal" Binding="{Binding B4R4,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged , Mode=TwoWay}" />
<mui:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Column5" Width="50" Header="Campuran" Binding="{Binding B4R5,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged , Mode=TwoWay}" />
.... till column29
```

The result is still like this :

How I can resolve the match width of column with scollbar visible like this?
[image]

## UPDATE

It still keep space in that although I have set the width..

[image]

## UPDATE 2

I don't know the scrollbar successfully resized but the space is still there
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can hide the Visibility of `ScrollBar` like this:

```
<DataGrid Name="dataGrid"
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ... />
```

Secondly, you can set a fixed `Width` for `ScrollBar`:

```
<Window x:Class="MyClass.MainWindow"
        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<DataGrid Name="dataGrid">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}">20</sys:Double>
        <sys:Double x:Key="{x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}">20</sys:Double>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
...
</DataGrid>
```

Thirdly, you can set the style for `ScrollBar`:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
        <Style.Triggers>                       
            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="10" />
                <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="10" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: It still doesn't work.. It still keep space in that although I have set the width.. you can see my update post in the image..

Comment: @mrhands: Then you can set the `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"`, set the fixed Width and to take this Width in `ColumnDefinition`.

Comment: @mrhands: Try set the Style for `ScrollBar`, please see my edit.

Comment: @mrhands: And as a result? It has helped?

Comment: Still no luck.. The scroll bar is successfully resized but the space still appear between last column and scrollbar.. I think the row has wider than the size of all columns.. The space in the red border I have set in the picture..

Comment: I'm still don't know what this code does mean .. `<ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=SampleDataGrid, Path=RowHeaderWidth}"`